# Bootscreen selections

Tags: 12.04, startup

RE: 12.04  on dual boot. I get a screen box with a few selections. The only one that works best is this: Generic 3.2.0.29-PAE recovery mode. The regular selection just Linux, if selected, I do not get a screen desktop that shows everything such as on the left side launcher column with the icons. Also, other selection is Linux previous versions and last is Win XP. Any ideas on this?

Comment: sam issue on my laptop. when selecting default boot system often doesn't load and i have to hard reboot.

Comment: is this a fresh installation? are you using it for the first time? then try a reinstalltion

Comment: for me issue occur no matter if system is "fresh" or not.